# Sharepoint/Power Apps, user can only see and edit own records within app

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

I am trying to edit my app in a way such that the user can only see and edit their own records. I am trying to do this within the app itself and not the list.

As I list I am aware I can restrict permissions. But I am trying to do this in the app.

I need to restrict but user().Email as I use this in a "Created by" field.

How can I restrict my "BrowseScreen" by user id?

**my items formula in growse gallery in browse screen:**

`SortByColumns(Filter([@'Template'], StartsWith('Purpose and objectives', TextSearchBox1.Text)), "Title", If(SortDescending1, Descending, Ascending))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try filtering `items` property of gallery control on "BrowseScreen" to something like:

```
Filter(DataSource, 'Created By'.Email = User().Email)
```

Where `DataSource` is your SharePoint list data source.

---

Update from comments:

```
SortByColumns(Filter([@'Template'], 'Created By'.Email = User().Email && StartsWith('Purpose and objectives', TextSearchBox1.Text)), "Title", If(SortDescending1, Descending, Ascending))
```

Comment: do I just append this to the previous "Items" formula with a comma?  also what is data source, just the name of it?

Comment: Try formula in updated answer.